# Cant export as .fbx file? Whats going on in here?

Tags: export, error, .fbx

I am trying to export my project as .fbx file so I can use it in UE4, but when i try to do it, I get this error in the picture below... What am i doing wrong? The project consists of multiple objects, there are no textures rn animations in it, just meshes.

TY!

[image]

[image]

export settings:

[image]

Comment: Hi, it's really difficult to say, I could just spot a repeating "int32" problem there... it could be some kind of conversion of overflow error, maybe, but your scene seems quite complex, and you didn't show/describe it, or your export settings... try if you can export a basic cube, so to be sure the exporter works, then try a copy of your file, and export only one object at a time, so to spot if the issue is specific for one of them, and report what found....

Comment: Instead of an image, can copy error message from system console.  Error is a keyerror,  eg when looking up a dictionary `dict[key]`  their is no value for key. The incorrect key is `(nan, nan)`  (not a number) returned from `_uv_tuples_gen(...)` and used to access some lookup table `uv2indx[key]`.  Suggest using the "Report a Bug" button of the fbx import addons preferences.

Comment: Hi, ty for your answers. I have tested the exporter on a normal cube and the exporter works just fine. I've managed to export the project as .obj with no problems (its just that in UE4 it imports it as one big mash, not separate objects, and as a very very tiny object). Edited the post with export settings.